# Android EDL mode commands

Tags: android, command-line, cmd, fastboot

I'm looking for commands to interact with an android device in EDL mode. There are different software which can interact with an EDL device, such as MiFlash and QFIL (Qualcomm Flash Image Loader). I searched for commands, fastboot like, but I found none. 
Is there a way I can flash a rom or at least get if there are edl devices connected to my pc with commands (from cmd for example)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To handle the phone in edl mode (download mode) we can use

- QPST
- QXDM

tools from qualcomm

Also you can run some commands with emmcdl a qualcomm tool also

https://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10-mobile/create-rawprogram0-xml-ffu-file-extract-t3385201

https://github.com/binsys/emmcdl/

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, Qualcomm's `lsusb` command will list EDL USB devices attached and show you the assigned COM port.

- It's usually included with MiFlash at `XiaoMiFlash\Source\ThirdParty\Qualcomm\fh_loader\lsusb.exe`
- (In fact, this is what MiFlash itself uses to identify the virtual COM port.)
- Once you know the COM port you can connect to the device with any serial terminal emulator (e.g. putty) and input raw commands directly.
- The EDL Firehose protocol is XML, you can see some examples in the MiFlash logs.

Outside Windows, there are some open source tools which might be useful

- https://github.com/openpst/sahara
- https://github.com/96boards/documentation/blob/master/consumer/guides/qdl.md

Not really what you're looking for but there are some interesting low level details on the Qualcomm secure boot sequence and primary and secondary bootloaders at
https://alephsecurity.com/2018/01/22/qualcomm-edl-1/